# How could I show my navigation bar over my body / section text?

Tags: html, css, navbar

My problem is when I scroll up, the text on the page goes through my navbar and it looks really unprofessional and I need to fix it. I want to make it so that my navigation bar is layered on top of my body / section text (body text includes navigation bar but section only includes text not on my nav bar),

I tried adding a background-color and that worked except when I used my dark / light mode switcher, I have css properties for dark mode and light mode but I can't use a background color otherwise when you switch, it will still show the background color for light mode (or whatever mode you were deigning for).

I also tried Z-Indexes since that is supposed to work but no, literally did nothing. Which was really weird. I wish I could elaborate more but that's all I can say, it just didn't work. Here is an example of what I did but I can't actually show you the exact code since I already deleted those Z-Indexes since they didn't work.

```
EXAMPLE NAV BAR CSS {
z-index: 100;
}

EXAMPLE SECTION / TEXT CSS {
z-index: -100;
}
```

Here's my navigation bar code:

```
    <ul>
        <div class="without-dark-ul">
            <img class="logo" width="100px" src="\imgs\logo.png">
            <h1 class="logo-side">[PRIVATE] Accounting</h1>
            <h2 class="logo-side-slogan">The best, afforadable accounting.</h2>
            <br>
            <hr>

            <h3 class="navbar-text">Navigation</h3>
            <div class="navbar">
                <li><a class="main-nav" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </div>

            <div class="vl"></div>
            <h3 class="dark-mode-text">Dark / Light Mode</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="ul-dark">
            <li class="li-dark">
                <span>Dark</span>
                <span>Light</span>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

And here's my CSS for my navbar (and I've got some in navbar CSS and some in dark mode CSS, I honestly don't know why I did it like that though.)

```
/* START NAVBAR */
.logo-side {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: -95px;
    font-size: 40px
    font-
}

.logo-side-slogan {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    /* position: -webkit-sticky; Safari */
    /* position: sticky; */
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
  }

  ul > hr {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-top: -10px;
  }
  
  li {
    float: left;
  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
  }
  
  li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(105, 103, 103);
  }
  
  .main-nav {
    background-color: #383838;
    color: white;
  }

.navbar {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.navbar-text {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #262626;
  position: absolute;
}

/* END NAVBAR */
```

```
/* START DARK MODE */ (This includes some nav bar CSS properties.)
.li-dark {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.ul-dark.active li {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
}

ul li span {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li span:nth-child(1) {
    background: #262626;
    color: #fff;
}

.ul-dark {
    position: static;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 320px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dark-mode-text { 
    margin-left: 320px;
    margin-top: -113px;
}

/* END DARK MODE */
```

I don't know if that is all you need but please ask me to send more code if you need more!

Thanks for your help.

- Solninja A

Comment: Also, add some text that overlaps the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

give a position relative to body and your text parent
and z-index:10000;

Comment: I will see if that will work, thanks for the reply.